# Does the location of a virtual image through a curved mirror depend on the observer's viewpoint?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics

Countless ray diagram demonstrations on the Internet simply ignore the observer when it comes to curved mirrors, and they're simply about convenient rays (parallel to the principal axis, converging at focus, etc.), which gives me the impression that the location of the virtual image is at one place, no matter where the observer observes it. I've only found [one diagram that specifically says the observer's view point must be on the principal axis](https://mammothmemory.net/physics/mirrors/convex-mirrors/convex-mirror-ray-diagram-rules.html) for the ray tracing method to work; and [this paper](https://my.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5610/handouts/curved-reflector.pdf) that says, unlike planar mirrors through which the virtual image doesn't ever change location, virtual images through curved mirrors change location depending on the observer's viewpoint (look for section "2.3. Planar Reflectors").

So does the location of a virtual image through a curved mirror depend on the observer's viewpoint? If that's the case, if the viewer's eye is not on the principal axis (which according to pretty much all demonstrations out there, is always positioned so that it goes through the center of the mirror's surface for no apparent reason as far as I can tell), should I choose my own principal axis that goes through the viewpoint for the ray diagram method to work?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Compare, e.g., the scene you see if you look thru refractive optics from off-center.  The optical systems are specifically designed to produce a miminum of distortion, focus error, etc. when the image region is centered on the optic axis.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft All the terms you're using are dashing over my head. Could you please dumb it down for someone who's not physics-inclined, so I could improve the clarity of my question?

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe it's this:  plane mirrors only "fold" the rays but don't affect the location of the focal plane.  Curved mirrors are analogous to lenses (see any introductory optics book) , so if you trace rays from an off-axis object, you can see where on the image plane the image will be, as well as any defocus, distortion effects which are a function of distance from the optic axis.  So just think of your "observer's viewpoint" as the same as inspecting a different part of the image plane

Comment: Currently the only clarity I can give you is slightly change the wording a bit and remove the unnecessary bit. I don't know what you mean by "off-center", "off-axis", "optic axis", "the optical systems are specifically designed...". The terms I used in my questions are referenced in the first link above, English isn't my native language, and again I'm not that physics-inclined, but merely trying to understand how to draw reflections as an artist. Could you please point out which part of the question you find unclear?